# Cancell task with parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I do have kind of endless loop where I do some operations. I would like to be able to cancell current opration with specific reason. However I cannot find a solution to cancell task with a paremetr.

```
private async void ProcessAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await Task<object>.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000);

                await Task.Delay(10000);

                return new object();

            }, _cts.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
        //catch (AnyOtherException)  
        //{
        //
        //} 
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to cancell task I call CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() method. The method does not accept any arguemnts. All I can do is to catch OperationCanceledException.

Is it another way to solve that or another way to achive what I want?

Comment: `async void` should only be used in event handlers. As for supplying a reason, that's not something related to *task cancellation*. Cancellation is just that - cancellation. There's no need to *throw* in case of cancellation, you could just return from the loop. The reason is an application/business-specific concern

Comment: PS, even after the edit, `async void` is a **very serious bug** which will probably result in early termination. Who's going to read this reason anway? How many reasons are there? Why should that reason go *through* the loop before it reaches whoever is going to read it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is fine to point out possible problems in suggested code, but a bit rude to question a reason for something. If there are multiple threads that can cancel this task, it could simply be a human readable error message that you want to show. You probably don't need the reason to go through the loop, I gather OP just wants the reason to be required in order to cancel the token.

Comment: @miechooy: Are you asking how to cancel the `Task.Run` delegate, or how to provide a human-readable reason for the cancellation?